# nfs error: NFS:v4 server does not accept raw uid gids reenabling the idmapper

Tags: linux, guid, nfs

I've created an NFS share on one server to clients
both server and clients are centos 6 system.
server nfs export:
**/srv/diskless/tmp     *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)**.

I mount **tmp** directory in clients, and login client as root, and when I edit files in tmp directory , sometimes it shows:***NFS:v4 server does not accept raw uid gids reenabling the idmapper.***
when I untar tar files in tmp directory, it shows:
***tar: text.cpp: Cannot change ownership to uid 2402, gid 30: Invalid argument***

So how to fix this or config nfs to ignore those issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

NFSv4 uses a string principals on the wire. You need to run rpc.idmapd ont the client and server which will take the responsibility to translate strings into numeris ids. Notice,that nfs4 domain on client and server should be the same.